# How to replace or swap an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am saving `myArray = [{a: 1, b:2}, {a:3, c:4}]` in localStorage with 
`JSON.stringify(myArray)`, parsing it with `JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('nameInLS'));`
and storing it in a variable called `localData`, which gives the following back, if `console.log` used:

```
[{a: 1, b:2}, {a:3, c4}]
```

My code works with `myArray` and my question is, how can I replace empty `myArray` (empty when site new reloaded) with `localData`?

It would also work if I could swap the content of both arrays.

The goal is, on page load, if localStorage is not empty, load content into `myArray`, later a function is called which builds a html table with the content of `myArray`

I tried weird things like:

```
myArray.push(localData) //worked but looked like this [[...]]
myArray = localData
localData = myArray //both didn't work
```

Thank you.

Comment: Why you state that `myArray = localData` does not work?

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: probably you mean `c: 4` instead of `c4` ?

Comment: Someone answered with myArray= [... localData];  and it is working. Also @Justinas you're right myArray = localData is working aswell... Iooks like I made a mistake during testing with myArray = localData. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

What's wrong with initially loading something from the localStorage?

If you try to save an object, this might not work. You need to convert it into a JSON string, like so:

```
const LOCAL_STORAGE_KEY = 'my-array';

// initial load
const rawValue = localStorage.getItem( LOCAL_STORAGE_KEY );
let myArray = rawValue ? JSON.parse( rawValue ) : [];

// do stuff
myArray.push( 'test' );

// save it back again
localStorage.setItem( LOCAL_STORAGE_KEY, JSON.stringify( myArray ) );
```